# How to check all items in CheckedListBox with vertical scroll bar with one click?

Tags: c#, checkbox, scrollbar, checkedlistbox

I have a CheckedListBox on my form with 13 items but it shows only 8 you need to use a vertical scroll bar to see the other 5 checkboxes.
The first item is "" if I check this, all other checkboxes which are shown at the moment will be checked, but the other 5 checkboxes won't be checked.

I use this code to check all checkboxes:

```
if (WochenTage_chbl.GetItemChecked(0))
{
     for (int i = 0; i < WochenTage_chbl.Items.Count; i++)
     {
        WochenTage_chbl.SetItemChecked(i, true);
     }
}
```

Do you know why only the shown checkboxes were checked?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Created a new WinForms app, plonked down a CheckedListBox, in Form_Load I added a loop to add 100 items with `checkedListBox1.Items.Add("Item" + i.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));`, and then added a button whose handler contains your code. I checked the first item in the listbox and clicked the button, and then all were checked - visible or not.

Comment: Do "the other 5 checkboxes" exist when your post code executes?

Comment: The code executes at the Event SelectedValueChanged

Comment: In the `ItemCheck` event, write this: `if (e.Index == 0) { for (int i = 1; i <  WochenTage_chbl.Items.Count; i++) { WochenTage_chbl.SetItemCheckState(i, e.NewValue); } }`